# How do I provide AffinityFunction.BackupFilter when mainly using C++ bindings

Tags: c++, ignite, gridgain

I am using the C++ bindings to have redundancy in my application. Alongside the main C++ node, I am running a vanilla Java node via `ignite.sh` as a backup on another node. I would like appoint this vanilla Java node to always stay a **backup** node and never a primary node as long as there is a C++ node running. Also, I need the C++ nodes to always stay as primary nodes. A little data loss is acceptable with the `PRIMARY_SYNC` synchronization.

My research led me to `AffinityFunction.BackupFilter` property to filter C++ nodes as primary. It seems that there is also some functions to give *attributes* to nodes. So I guess I can set a specific attribute on C++ nodes and filter them to always stay as primary nodes.

However, C++ bindings apparently neither provide a way to set backup filter nor allow setting attributes on the launched node. I have noticed some modules get plugged through `ignite-dir/libs` but there is no tutorial about that approach to add `AffinityFunction`. How can I achieve what I need? I need to plug a custom affinity function while using C++ as the main and a way to distinguish the C++ nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignite adds the files in `ignite_dir/libs` into classpath. According to the documentation, environment variables can be read via `ClusterNode.attribute()` method. So I have put the following java code to `libs/` folder:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.ignite.cluster.ClusterNode;
import org.apache.ignite.lang.IgniteBiPredicate;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.*;

public class RendezvousAffinityFunction extends org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.RendezvousAffinityFunction {
        @Override
        public List<List<ClusterNode>> assignPartitions(AffinityFunctionContext affCtx) {
                System.out.println("Assigning partitions...");

                List<List<ClusterNode>> partitions = super.assignPartitions(affCtx);

                for (List<ClusterNode> nodes : partitions) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); ++i) {
                                ClusterNode node = nodes.get(i);
                                boolean is_primary_instance = ((Object)node.attribute("IGNITE_PRIMARY_NODE") != null);

                                if (is_primary_instance && i != 0) {
                                        // move to the top of the node list
                                        nodes.remove(i);
                                        nodes.add(0, node);

                                        System.out.println("Putting node " + i + " to the head of the node list.");
                                }
                        }
                }

                return partitions;
        }
}
```

Apparently, this method is called on topology change. The method override checks the environment variable `IGNITE_PRIMARY_NODE`, if it exists, it puts the node at the beginning of the `ClusterNode` list which is then used as the primary node by Ignite. This override will prefer the nodes with `IGNITE_PRIMARY_NODE` environment variable set as the primary nodes.

Answer (score 3):

This is discussed on Apache Ignite user forum: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/How-do-I-provide-AffinityFunction-BackupFilter-when-mainly-using-C-bindings-td11930.html